# Initializing two doubly linked lists C++

Tags: c++, struct, null, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to initialize my two doubly linked lists to empty but my program is crashing. The program separates even and odd integers from a text file. I believe the problem lies within the InitializeList function but I've tried several different things to no avail.  I need to initialize them both to :

```
Odds->top = NULL;
Odds->length = 0;

Evens->top = NULL;
Evens->length = 0;
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int integer;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};
struct list{
    int length;
    node *top;
};
bool EmptyList(list* head)
{
    bool empty;

    if(head == NULL)
        empty = true;
    else
        empty = false;

    return empty;
}

list* InitializeList(list* A_list)
{
    A_list->top = NULL;
    A_list->length = 0;
    return A_list;
}
bool OrderedListInsertion(list* &A_list, int number, int &counter)
{
    bool repeat,
         success;
    node *newOdd;
    node *newEven;
    node *EvenHead;
    node *oddHead;



    if((number % 2) == 0)
    {
        A_list = new list;
        newEven = new (nothrow) node;
        A_list->top = newEven;
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            if(newEven == NULL)
            {
                cout << "ERROR. Memory allocation failed!" << endl;
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                newEven->integer = number;
                newEven->next = NULL;
                newEven->prev = NULL;
                EvenHead = newEven;
                success = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(newEven == NULL)
            {
                cout << "ERROR. Memory allocation failed!" << endl;
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                newEven->integer = number;
                newEven->prev = EvenHead;
                newEven->next = NULL;
                EvenHead = newEven;
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if((number % 2) != 0)
    {
        A_list = new list;
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            newOdd = new (nothrow) node;
            if(newOdd == NULL)
            {
                cout << "ERROR. Memory allocation failed!" << endl;
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                newOdd->integer = number;
                newOdd->prev = NULL;
                oddHead = newOdd;
                newOdd->next = NULL;
                success = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newOdd = new (nothrow) node;
            if(newOdd == NULL)
            {
                cout << "ERROR. Memory allocation failed!" << endl;
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                newOdd->integer = number;
                newOdd->prev = newOdd;
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return success;

}
int ReadFirst(list* &Odds, list* &Evens)
{
    string file1 = "Int1.txt";
    ifstream ReadInts;
    int number;
    int x = 0,
        y = 0;
    bool success;

    ReadInts.open(file1.c_str());
    ReadInts >> number;
    do
    {
        if((number % 2) == 0)
        {
            success = OrderedListInsertion(Evens, number, x);
            if(success)
            {
                x++;
                cout << "Even processed." << endl;
            }
            else
                return 1;
        }
        if((number % 2) != 0)
        {
            success = OrderedListInsertion(Odds, number, y);
            if(success)
            {
                y++;
                cout << "Odd processed." << endl;
            }
            else
                return 1;
        }
        ReadInts >> number;
    }while(ReadInts);

    ReadInts.close();

}
int main()
{
    list* Odds;
    list* Evens;

    Odds = InitializeList(Odds);
    Evens = InitializeList(Evens);
    ReadFirst(Odds, Evens);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program compiles but doesn't display anything when it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Odds` and `Evens` variables are just pointers. But what do they point to?

You need to allocate some memory or do something else so that they point to valid memory. As it is, you pass them to `InitializeList()`, which sets properties that don't even exist.

Since you don't even initialize these pointers, there's no telling what value they have, which means there is no telling what memory they point to.

Something like the following (untested) would make much more sense.

```
list Odds;
list Evens;

InitializeList(&Odds);
InitializeList(&Evens);
ReadFirst(&Odds, &Evens);
```

Here, the lists are not pointers. They are full objects. And then you are just passing pointers to those objects to the other functions.

Comment: Don't forget to make the response that is most helpful as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `InitializeList()` does not initilize the `A_list`, so if the `A_list` is null, then you can't reference it as `A_list->top`

```
list* InitializeList(list* A_list)
{
    A_list->top = NULL;
    A_list->length = 0;
    return A_list;
}
```

See how you call it:

```
list* Odds

Odds = InitializeList(Odds);
```

`Odds` is just pointing nothing, so you get an error in `InitializeList()`

To initialize the `list`, you should do

```
list* Odds = new list
```